# How to disable GRUB prompt after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop and it is booting to the GRUB prompt. This is the regular prompt, not the rescue:

[image]

At this prompt I just need to issue the `exit` command and the boot process resumes successfully. Ubuntu itself is running flawlessly.

How can I disable this GRUB prompt?